# Max-width px width 100%

Tags: html, css

Seems trivial but I seem to be struggling with this. I have a container div and content within. The page needs to be responsive so naturally I am using max width (in px) on everything.

I have added width: 100% to the div, h2 and p tags, but the width does not expand to the max-width. How can I get the divs to expand to their max size without explicitly setting the width to this fixed value?

css and html

```css
.container {max-width:1200px; width:100%;}
.container h2 {max-width:400px; width:100%;}
.container p {max-width:900px; width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamically populated using PHP</h2>
  <p>Dynamically populated using PHP</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT: It was css buried in other divs causing the issue, the code above works.**

Comment: Describe the error image or provide an example of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the semi-colons after the width rules.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamically populated using PHP</h2>
    <p>Dynamically populated using PHP</p>
</div>

.container {max-width:1200px; width:100%; background-color: red;}
.container h2 {max-width:400px; width:100%; background-color: blue;}
.container p {max-width:900px; width:100%; background-color: green;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kr1b92mu/

I added the background colors to show that it's working :).

Comment: *the semi-colons after the width* doesn't affect if it's the last property .... The code of the OP is working

Answer (score 0):

The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of an element.
This prevents the value of the width property from becoming larger than max-width.
It is a "limit".

The width property is the one how stablish the  exact width of an element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp